# Is there a workaround for using LIMIT in a subquery in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1235

Here is my original query...

```
SELECT `id`
  FROM `properties`
 LIMIT 10, 20
```

The `LIMIT` condition is for pagination.

Now, I have to get all like before, but I need to get only a third of rows where a condition is present.

I came up with this, just throwing `LIMIT 30` in before I figured out how to do (total rows matched / 3) * 2.

```
SELECT `id`
  FROM `properties`
 WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` 
                      FROM `properties` 
                     WHERE `vendor` = "abc" 
                  ORDER BY RAND() 
                     LIMIT 30)
LIMIT 10, 20
```

MySQL said...

> 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

I guess I can't use `LIMIT` in a subquery.

So this is a multi question but all related...

- Is there a workaround for `LIMIT` in subquery?
- Can I select a 1/3 of matched rows with MySQL?
- Do I need to turn this into 2 queries, or just select all and unset the rows not required in PHP?

Comment: One obvious thing that springs to mind is that *random results* and *pagination* don't really go together...

Comment: @deceze Yeah, I figured that when doing it in PHP. So I just took the first 1/3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your version of MySQL doesn't support that then you have 2 options:

- Upgrade.  Always fun, and it's generally best to be on the latest version.
- Break out your subquery using php.  Grab the ids, then format the results into a comma separated string.

Comment: On a shared host, so can't upgrade. However, I did it in PHP. :) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry I'm late, this worked for me:

```
   SELECT p.id 
     FROM properties p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.id
             FROM PROPERTIES t
            WHERE t.vendor = 'abc'
         ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 30) x ON x.id = p.id
    WHERE x.id IS NULL
    LIMIT 10, 20
```

Comment: Thanks OMG Ponies, already did it in PHP but I'll learn something from this. +1

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does support LIMIT in a subquery...but MySQL does NOT support using IN/NOT IN with a subquery.

To be honest I really don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just a weird request by a client - "I want to show all properties, but only a random 1/3 by a specific vendor".